# Shell: how to go to the beginning of line when you are inside a screen?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, keyboard-shortcuts

I am inside a screen (screen -Ra). I have a long command, and I am at the end. Instead of keeping the left arrow, how can you go to the beginning of the line?

CTRL-A works when I am in a normal window, but when I am inside a screen pressing CTRL-A gives me a message "No other window" - seems like CTRL-A is dispatched to the screen.

How do you go to the beginning of a line in  a screen?

Comment: Quick fix: press the `Home` key to get to the beginning, and `End` to get to the end of line.

Comment: This is also highly dependent upon the shell and input mode youre using, though I'm assuming youre using bash and the default emacs bindings.

Comment: @hesse given your keyboard has a `Home` button. Not always the case

Comment: The OP might be interested in this [related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57227/replacement-shortcuts-for-screen).

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>, or change screen's escape keystroke (option `-e`).

Comment: In case it is not clear you press `Ctrl`-`a`, release both keys, and then press `a`.  Do not make the same mistake I made keeping `Ctrl` pressed.  Good reference card for this and other key bindings: http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference

Answer (score 13):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> lets you go to the first character of the line for any readline-compatible environment like Bash, python and mysql. GNU SCREEN safely ignores this. No customized configuration necessary.

If you use this instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>, you use a consistant shortcut key - you don't have to keep in mind whether you are in GNU SCREEN or not.

For anyone interested, the same shortcut key also lets you go to the end of the line if you are already at the begining.

Comment: Actually, `C-x C-x` is `exchange-point-and-mark`.  It just happens that mark is at the beginning of the line by default.  You can use `C-space` to set the mark somewhere else.

Comment: Ivan, typically what can you do after exchanging a point and marking ? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Either you can change the `screen` bindings or you can change the bindings of your shell. Assuming your shell is `bash`, the output of `bind -p | grep \C-a` should give you the current action binded to `Ctrl+A`. To bind this action to something else use the following form:

```
$ bind '"\C-p": beginning-of-line'
```

This will bind `Ctrl+P` to move the cursor to the beginning of the line. Remember the double-quotes inside the expression. To unset a binding you would just set it to nothing:

```
$ bind '"\C-a": '
```

To list all input sequences associated with the action, use:

```
$ bind -p | grep beginning-of-line
```

Lastly, to make the bindings permament you can put the statements in your `~/.bashrc` file and issue `source ~/.bashrc`.