# Move to the beginning of a line in screen

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shell: how to go to the beginning of line when you are inside a screen?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29450/shell-how-to-go-to-the-beginning-of-line-when-you-are-inside-a-screen)

Normally to get to the beginning of a line in a terminal the command is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>.

While using GNU screen the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> is the escape sequence to enter a screen command.

Is there a default way to move to the beginning of a line while in screen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sequence to send a literal <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> is explained in the man page:

```
   C-a a       (meta)        Send the command character (C-a)  to  window.
                             See escape command.
```

so you should use <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>.

So, if you have a screen inside the other (for example screen + ssh + screen) you should use that prescription multiple time, and in the case at hand it becomes <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>

Comment: Nice!  I had always thought since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+(<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>) switched screens that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> would do the same but the release of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key after the initial <kbd>a</kbd> makes it perform the default action <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> when not in a screen.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just configure (if it's required - does it work out of the box?) your home key so it works correctly. Here's [a randomly googled reference](http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard.html)