# Replacement shortcuts for `screen`

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnu-screen

Screen uses the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to activate. I find that this interferes with the Bash command for jumping to the start of the line, and the VIM command for incrementing an integer. Certainly I could just remap it, but I am interested to know how other screen users deal with the situation. I don't think that I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> for anything. What drawbacks and gotchas have other screen users encountered when changing the default shortcut?

Note that I was unsure if Unix.SE or SuperUser would be more appropriate a place to post this. This could be a ["chatty, open-ended question"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq) or it could be a very useful resource for other screen users who undoubtedly encounter this, depending on how disciplined the answers are. I suspect that other screen users will more likely stumble across the question on Unix.SE. If SuperUser is a more appropriate place then any mod is welcomed to move it. Thanks!

Comment: Hitting `C-a a` will send `C-a` to the terminal

Comment: Different strokes for different folks. This is a poll question, and those don't do well on Stack Exchange. For the poll: I use `C-\`, which few applications use.

Comment: Thanks Jordanm, I happen to know that. But I find that extra keystroke breaks all continuity, so instead of the fingers just doing the thinking the brain must get involved. Maybe I'm just a VIM-spoiled brat!

Comment: Then you should be using vi-mode in your shell, surely? :)

Comment: @jasonwryan: Actually, I hated VI-mode in the shell. For single-lines of text I find the default Bash / Emacs shortcuts preferable, especially as the only one that I really need is to jump to the beginning of a line or such (other than history).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> is probably not a good idea unless you remap the `start` terminal key, for example, to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>:

```
stty start '^X'
```

This is the complement of the `stop` character (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>), which suspends output to the terminal from the OS.

Myself, I've been using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> for over twenty years.  I don't often suspend things since I can just create a new window, but if I do need to, then I just hit it twice.

Comment: Thank you. Ctrl-Z was my first inclination, but I do sometimes suspend VIM when a simple `:!` is too little but a new window is too much.

Comment: That's when I would use `:shell`.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this years ago, and decided I would permanently bless <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> to be screen's shortcut key. In your `.screenrc`:

```
escape "^]]"
```

Then you still have Ctrl-A for all begninning of line goodies in Emacs, GNU readline, etc.

Comment: Thanks. However VIM uses that shortcut with ctags to jump to the definition of a function.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution to be to remap the `screen` activation shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>. This has the advantage of only one hand leaving home row, and that hand does not have to do any contortions to press any other keys. The VIM mapping of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> merely inserts a linefeed (useless, I didn't even know about it) and the Bash mapping of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> presents the text of a search for editing (again, a mapping I didn't even know about and has a sensible workaround).

I hope that other `screen` users find this helpful.

Comment: Normally, I've used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> after some curses program has crashed, since I need some way to reset the terminal to accept commands again (carriage returns won't work).  I'd type in `stty sane<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>`.  Don't think I'd give this up for 'leaving home row'.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Arcege! I was unaware of that particular use case.