# Ctrl-a does not take me to the beginning of the prompt while I am working within a GNU screen

Tags: keyboard, gnu-screen, readline

To navigate to the starting and end of a command, I usually use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>.

However, when I work within a GNU screen, those keybinding do not work becuase perhaps they are being used by the GNU screen. Is there another way to move to the starting or the end of the command?

I am on CentOS6.2

Comment: Duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29450/44406

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ctrl-A followed by the letter 'a' will send the Ctrl-A sequence to the shell.

Or you could map the screen command key to something other than Ctrl-A

Answer (score 4):

The default readline binding for `beginning-of-line` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>. As this conflicts with `screen`'s command prefix, you can either rebind the screen prefix, as suggested by [Johnny](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72120/6761), or include another binding in your `.inputrc` to map the readline behaviour to another keybind, for example to map the same behaviour to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, you could use:

```
"\ea": beginning-of-line
```

This will allow you to use either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> outside of `screen` and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> within.

All of the [readline bindings](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC13) can be customized for both Emacs (the default) or vi mode.

A full list of all of the readline commands is availbale here:
http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_readline.htm

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> is often used by emacs and the shells' emacs mode.  What I generally do is use `screen`'s `escape` command to set the key sequence to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>.  Most of the time, I'm not looking to stop a program only to run another - for that, I open a new `screen` window and run the program.  When I do, it is easy enought to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> <kbd>z</kbd>.  Also, I very often `ssh` to other systems and run `screen` there, where I might use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> as well.