# How do I go to beginning of command line when I am inside the screen?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnu-screen

In bash I can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>a</kbd> and go to first of the command line.

But in `screen` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>a</kbd> does not do this. How do I go to first of command line in screen?

Comment: `set -o vi`: `Space` (if you are in insert mode) `0`. Done :)

Comment: I use a less invasive prefix: `escape ^\\\ ` (Ctrl+backslash, press backslash again to send a literal chr(28))

Comment: Duplicates: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29450/shell-how-to-go-to-the-beginning-of-line-when-you-are-inside-a-screen, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72119/ctrl-a-does-not-take-me-to-the-beginning-of-the-prompt-while-i-am-working-within

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> followed by <kbd>a</kbd> to go to the beginning of the line. The <kbd>a</kbd> sends a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

#### The long way

Take a look at this Q&A from SuperUser, titled: [Bash vs. Gnu screen : Replace Ctrl-A with Ctrl-Shift-A](https://superuser.com/questions/142680/bash-vs-gnu-screen-replace-ctrl-a-with-ctrl-shift-a). There are several options but the easiest would be to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to something else for `screen` so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> can be freed for use by Bash.

*excerpt from one of the answers*

> By default, C-a C-a is bound to the other command (switch to most
>   recently active screen) in screen. To have C-a C-a send an actual C-a
>   and have C-a o switch windows, put the following in your .screenrc:
>
> ```
> escape ^A^A
> bind o other
> ```

#### The short way

As @jordanm has pointed out in the comments. The above solution isn't necessary, however. The 2nd highest upvoted answer to that same Q&A states that you can simply type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and `screen` will send a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to Bash.

Comment: I don't necessary want to use `C+a`. Is there any shortcut specific to `screen`?

Comment: You failed to mention the second most upvoted answer in that thread http://superuser.com/a/237223/190213. It's the most straightforward (IMO) and the method I personally use.

Comment: @jordanm - didn't scroll that far down. 8-). I've never run into this issue, I use tmux.

Comment: @Mohsen - see updates.